# CSS transparent background not working in IE7-8

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm slowly deleting a few small png files I used for transparent divs, and replacing them with CSS code.

This CSS code works on FF and IE9-10, and it helps in styling a textbox (it also changes the background when you click on it and adds a red 1px border):

```
#searchbars input {
    width: 130px;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    padding: 4px 2px 2px 10px;
    font-size: .9em;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    height: 16px;

    /* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
    background: rgb(22, 22, 22) transparent; /* #161616 /
    /* RGBa with 0.28 opacity */
    background: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.28);
    color: #FFF;
}

#searchbars input:active,
#searchbars input:focus {
    /* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
    background: rgb(22, 22, 22) transparent; /* #161616 /
    /* RGBa with 0.75 opacity */
    background: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.75); 
    border: 1px solid #ff8277;
}
```

Here's the conditional stylesheet for IE7:

```
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
    #searchbars input {
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#47161616, endColorstr=#47161616);
}

#searchbars input:active, #searchbars input:focus {
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#bf161616, endColorstr=#bf161616);
}
```

IE8 conditional sheet:

```
    /* For IE 8*/
   #searchbars input {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#47161616, endColorstr=#47161616)";
}

#searchbars input:active, #searchbars input:focus {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#bf161616, endColorstr=#bf161616)";
}
```

I used IE10 developer tool, and tried to render the page using IE7-8-9 engines.

IE9/10/Firefox -> everything works as expected

IE8 -> Default background and the background change when you click on the textbox (`input:focus`) are not the ones expected. It seems that opacity is not being applied even though the alpha hex values are correct.

IE7 -> Default background works. Background change when you click on the textbox (`input:focus`) doesn't work. 
Also, the textbox border doesn't turn red when you click on it (see `border: 1px solid #ff8277;` property from the original sheet)

Here's a demo page: http://www.flapane.com/calcio.php

The search box is in the upper right corner, right of the social sharing buttons.

Any hints?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't really an answer, and I wouldn't be surprised if it was downvoted, but have you heard of progressive enhancement?

Comment: This should already cover 99% of the browser visiting me (as per Google Analytics stats).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is that the regular `background` declarations interfere with the `filters`.

To fix it, add `background: none` to your `inputs` in LTE IE8 only, either through a second stylesheet or in the same document but by appending `\9` to the declaration.

`background: none\9;` targets IE8 and below, just like the wildcard hack (`*background: none;`) which targets IE7 and below, or the underscore hack (`_background: none;`) which targets IE6 and below. You should however only need to use the first.

Comment: Thank you so much, it seems that you found the solution. Unfortunately, it seems that it fixed the IE8 issue only, while on IE7 the background still doesn't change when I click on the textbox, and the border still doesn't turn red. I tried either adding the declaration in the two conditional stylesheets or directly in a `<!--[if lte IE 8]>`, but the result is the same.

Comment: That's not very weird seeing as IE7 doesn't support :focus. There might be a polyfill for adding :focus support in lte IE7, but I honestly think you should ditch support for IE7. I mean, your site still seems to work fine in IE7, it's just a minor detail. :-)

Comment: Why didn't I check if IE7 support :focus? That explains everything... thanks again. :)